# Getting an AttributeError when attempting to assign IntVar() to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Jan 22 14:47:36 2017

@author: Jose Chong
"""
import json
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

import os
import pymsgbox

filepath = os.path.expanduser(r'~\Documents\joseDzirehChongToDoList\toDoListSaveFile.json')

checkboxList = []

def checkSaveFile():

    def checkExistenceOfSaveFile():
        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.expanduser(r'~\Documents\joseDzirehChongToDoList')):
            os.makedirs(os.path.expanduser(r'~\Documents\joseDzirehChongToDoList'), 777)

        if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
            open(filepath, 'w')
            open(filepath).close()

    def checkIfSaveFileIsEmpty():
        global checkboxList
        if os.path.getsize(filepath) == 0:
            with open (filepath, 'w') as outfile:
                    json.dump(checkboxList, outfile)


        with open(filepath) as infile:    
             checkboxList = json.load(infile)
    checkExistenceOfSaveFile()
    checkIfSaveFileIsEmpty()
    try:
        open(filepath, 'w')
        open(filepath).close()
    except (IOError, ValueError):

        pymsgbox.alert("""You're not supposed to see this message ever. If you do, that means your save file is either missing or corrupted, and my methods of stopping that have failed. Please email me at 'josedzirehchong@gmail.com' with a copy of your save file so I can tell what went wrong.

Click the button below to exit, the red button in the corner doesn't work.""", 'Broken Save File')

checkSaveFile()

var = tk.IntVar()

def loadToJSON():
    with open(filepath, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(checkboxList, outfile)

class CheckboxRow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, text):
        self.text = text
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=text, variable=var)
        checkbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        deleteItem = tk.Button(self, text="x", bg="red", fg="white",
                                activebackground="white", activeforeground="red",
                                command=self.destroyCheckbox)
        deleteItem.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        newItem = [self.text, var.get()]
        self.master.master.checkboxList.append(newItem)
        loadToJSON()

    def destroyCheckbox(self, text):
        self.text = text
        newItem = [self.text, var.get()]
        self.master.master.checkboxList.remove(newItem)
        self.destroy()
        loadToJSON()


class CheckboxArea(tk.Frame):
    def add(self, name):
        row = CheckboxRow(self, name)
        row.pack(fill=tk.X)

class InputStuff(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        prompt = tk.Label(self, text="What do you want your checkbox to be for?")
        prompt.pack()

        bottomInput = tk.Frame(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(bottomInput, bd=3)
        self.entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        buttonConfirm = tk.Button(bottomInput, text="Confirm", command=self.drawCheckbox)
        buttonConfirm.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        bottomInput.pack()

        buttonDone = tk.Button(self, text = "Close Input", command=master.hideInputStuff)
        buttonDone.pack()

    def drawCheckbox(self, event=None):
        self.master.add(self.entry.get())
        self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        self.checkboxList = []

        self.checkboxArea = CheckboxArea(self)
        self.checkboxArea.pack(fill=tk.X)

        self.inputStuff = InputStuff(self)
        self.addButton = tk.Button(self, text="Add Item", command=self.showInputStuff)

        self.hideInputStuff() # start with "add" button active

        self.load()

    def load(self):
        for savedCheckbox in checkboxList:
            checkboxRow = tk.Frame(checkboxArea)
            checkboxRow.pack(fill=tk.X)
            checkbox1 = tk.Checkbutton(checkboxRow, text=savedCheckbox[0], variable=var)
            checkbox1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            deleteItem = tk.Button(checkboxRow, text="x", bg="red", fg="white",
                                activebackground="white", activeforeground="red",
                                command=lambda c=savedCheckbox, r=checkboxRow: destroyCheckbox(c, r))
            deleteItem.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

            loadToJSON()

    def add(self, name):
        self.checkbox_area.add(name)
        self.checkboxList.append(name)

    def showInputStuff(self):
        self.addButton.pack_forget()
        self.input_stuff.pack()
        self.input_stuff.entry.focus()
        self.master.bind('<Return>', self.input_stuff.drawCheckbox)

    def hideInputStuff(self):
        self.inputStuff.pack_forget()
        self.addButton.pack()
        self.master.unbind('<Return>')

def main():
    master = tk.Tk()
    master.title("To-Do List (with saving!)")
    master.geometry("300x300")
    win = MainWindow(master)
    win.pack(fill=tk.X)
    master.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It's horribly broken, I know. I don't want help with any of the other stuff, just the AttributeError.

Full error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Josalina/Desktop/Coding/Language - Python/to-do-list-to-compile/toDoListToCompile.py', wdir='C:/Users/Josalina/Desktop/Coding/Language - Python/to-do-list-to-compile')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-78-a1f8f63a42cc>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Josalina/Desktop/Coding/Language - Python/to-do-list-to-compile/toDoListToCompile.py', wdir='C:/Users/Josalina/Desktop/Coding/Language - Python/to-do-list-to-compile')

  File "C:\Users\Josalina\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Josalina\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Josalina/Desktop/Coding/Language - Python/to-do-list-to-compile/toDoListToCompile.py", line 51, in <module>
    var = tk.IntVar()

  File "C:\Users\Josalina\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)

  File "C:\Users\Josalina\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 233, in __init__
    self._root = master._root()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'
```

I have no idea what this means. Isn't IntVar() a standard part of Tkinter? Why is it raising an error? How do I fix it? Also, fixing this error probably won't make the program run, it'll just let me move on to the next error. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Tkinter program you *must* initialize Tkinter by creating a root window before you do anything else. However, your code attempts to create that StringVar before you create the root window.

FWIW, we can reproduce that error in a couple of lines:

```
import tkinter as tk
var = tk.IntVar()
```

which results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./qtest.py", line 4, in <module>
    var = tk.IntVar()
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 499, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 314, in __init__
    self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'
```

So you need to define `var` after the `master = tk.Tk()` call is executed. It can still be a global variable, but you really should try to avoid that, especially since you're already using classes to structure your data.

---

I should also mention that the `tk.Tk()` call doesn't merely create the root window. It first creates an instance of a [Tcl/tk](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk_(software)) interpreter; Python Tkinter code is essentially a wrapper around the Tcl/tk calls that create and run the GUI.